# Please rename tag [typo] to [source-error]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

As a discussion in [this thread](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/what-is-a-better-name-for-the-tag-typo), please rename tag [typo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) (currently 21 questions) to [source-error](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-error) (currently nonexistent).

I could retag them one by one, but doing so would bump the questions on the top page.  Only moderators can rename tags without bumping the questions.