# Should we burninate the [source-error] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [source-error](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-error) tag, which was the pet project of one particular high reputation user who hasn't been around for more than a year and a half.  It seems that since they left, no one else has thought it was a good idea to tag "typo" questions in this manner.  (This tag was previously known as [typo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo).)

This has been previously discussed [in meta comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/what-is-a-better-name-for-the-tag-typo#comment2154_838), where the chief proponent of the tag wrote:

> Voting to closing is fine. I also tried that in the past. But five votes are required, and as I wrote in the description of the tag, it usually does not get closed. The tag was a workaround for the problem.

I don't think this is a valid solution to the perceived problem.  If the questions should be closed, we should close them; we shouldn't tag them "please ignore this question, it should be closed".  I think that the [source-error](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-error) tag is a [**meta tag**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/); it could never appear on its own because it doesn't tell you anything useful about the question content itself.

I've brought this up on chat before, and so has Troyen, but it looks like we've never gotten around to removing the tag.  Shall we?

Comment: I was about to say it looks like a meta tag too.

Comment: Now that "Too localised" doesn't exist, what close reason would be used? On a different note, it feels kind of wrong to close a question when the OP themself didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm They do that on Stack Overflow - when someone makes a syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, please remove it. Tags are useful for 2 reasons,  in my opinion:

- to categorise questions for the benefit of people answering them (which becomes more beneficial when there's more questions on the site),
- to make searching easier.

Meta-tags as the one in question don't really serve any of those purposes. Moreover, they create confusion as they make the usage of the tags system more murky, especially for inexperienced users.

Comment: Plus, the tag would have to be edited into the question _afterwards_ (by someone), resulting in more work (and unnecessary bumping of questions). I agree to get rid of the tag. I guess, the close reason would be a comment in this case?

Comment: Make no mention of the fact that you can only have 5 tags on a question, so it's using up space there, as well.