# Source-error tag cleanup: should we close any of these old questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now, it looks like we're going to [destroy the source-error tag](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1181/1478).   This tag was the pet project of one high reputation user who [described its purpose](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/what-is-a-better-name-for-the-tag-typo#comment2154_838) this way:

> Voting to closing is fine. I also tried that in the past. But five votes are required, and as I wrote in the description of the tag, it usually does not get closed. The tag was a workaround for the problem.

But this isn't really an appropriate use for a tag.  There are really two possibilities:

- If a user misread something or someone made a typo, then it's possible the question won't be of any use to anyone in the future.  If so, perhaps we should **close** it.  See: [How should we handle "typo" questions now that Too Localized is gone?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1185/1478)
- Or perhaps the error is linguistically interesting ("No, *this* isn't grammatical; you need to say *this*") and adds value to the site.  If so, we can leave it **open**, using answers to describe the errors rather than tags.

Right now, **thirty-five questions** are tagged [source-error](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-error).  Before we destroy this tag, let's take a moment to review these questions and decide whether they should be closed as typo questions.  We've added a custom close reason for this purpose:

> This question was caused by **a simple spelling mistake, misreading, or typographical error**.  While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.  For more information, see [our meta discussion on "typo questions"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/).

Here's the list:

1. [What's the standard way of explaining reason in response to the question "why?"? Do you use からです at the end?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6493/1478)
2. [Is あたり used only to enumerate items?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6427/1478)
3. [What is the correct veritable meaning of 水無月 and 神無月?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6275/1478)
4. [Is くろじん a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6120/1478)
5. [Why did the author use hiragana instead of kanji in the following examples? (長い,幼い)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6039/1478)
6. [は as sentence final particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5969/1478)
7. [What is the original Japanese for "It's always the darkest under the lighthouse"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5829/1478)
8. [What does ワソマソ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5622/1478)
9. [What does なきや mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5491/1478)
10. [kanji composition question -- why these radicals for 出?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5393/1478)
11. [Difference between 颜 and 顔](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5334/1478)
12. [Trying to translate 遊ばにゃ損なってなもんだろうがおう！](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5107/1478)
13. [一ヵ条: いちっかじょう? いちかじょう? いっかじょう?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4865/1478)
14. [What is the etymology of the word しょーむない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4775/1478)
15. [Can I use [自称]{じしょう}ほど for things other than namesake?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4511/1478)
16. [Stem classification 終止形 vs 連体形（しゅうしけい vs れんたいけい）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4375/1478)
17. [What is the correct reading for べき乗打切り待機法?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4207/1478)
18. [What does お土産持しててね mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3960/1478)
19. ["To call" or "To receive a call"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3810/1478)
20. [抱った vs 抱いた and 書った vs 書いた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3775/1478)
21. [What is the difference between 「食べるいいですか」 and 「食べていいですか」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3643/1478)
22. [What is ~なかって and how is it formed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3499/1478)
23. [What is あっちゃう in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3498/1478)
24. [two levels for teiru and rare](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3363/1478)
25. [雨を降っています - grammatically correct sentence or just typo?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3272/1478)
26. [Does the だ get dropped after an い-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3149/1478)
27. [「ありがとうございや」 - Dialect? Train Station 言葉？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3131/1478)
28. [What Does 火信 Mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2542/1478)
29. [Meaning of しやしま as sentence ender](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2428/1478)
30. [What does やい mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1657/1478)
31. [Pronunciation and meaning of ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1472/1478)
32. *(already closed)* [Figuring out Aに助かりました](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2283/1478)
33. *(already closed)* [Superdry. 極度乾燥(しなさい)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6434/1478)
34. *(already closed)* [Is 胡 missplaced in the Kodansha Kanji Learner's Dictionary?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3997/1478)
35. *(already closed)* https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2830/1478

What do you think?  Do any of these questions need to be closed?  If so, please **vote to close** using the new custom close reason (or any other reason you believe is appropriate).

Note: There's no need to remove the tag from any of these questions right now.  It'll be removed from all of them at the same time when the tag is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twenty-four hours later . . .

## 10 questions have been closed as off-topic:

1. [What does なきや mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5491/1478) (closed)
2. [What does お土産持しててね mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3960/1478) (closed)
3. [抱った vs 抱いた and 書った vs 書いた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3775/1478) (closed)
4. [What is ~なかって and how is it formed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3499/1478) (closed)
5. [What is あっちゃう in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3498/1478) (closed)
6. [雨を降っています - grammatically correct sentence or just typo?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3272/1478) (closed)
7. [What Does 火信 Mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2542/1478) (closed)
8. [Meaning of しやしま as sentence ender](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2428/1478) (closed)
9. [What does やい mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1657/1478) (closed)
10. [Pronunciation and meaning of ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1472/1478) (closed)

## 3 questions remain open *with* close votes:

1. [What does ワソマソ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5622/1478) (4 close votes)
2. [Difference between 颜 and 顔](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5334/1478) (2 close votes)
3. [What is the original Japanese for "It's always the darkest under the lighthouse"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5829/1478) (1 close vote)

## 18 questions remain open *without* close votes:

1. [What's the standard way of explaining reason in response to the question "why?"? Do you use からです at the end?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/1478)
2. [Is あたり used only to enumerate items?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/1478)
3. [What is the correct veritable meaning of 水無月 and 神無月?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/1478)
4. [Is くろじん a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/1478)
5. [Why did the author use hiragana instead of kanji in the following examples? (長い,幼い)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6039/1478)
6. [は as sentence final particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/1478)
7. [kanji composition question -- why these radicals for 出?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/1478)
8. [Trying to translate 遊ばにゃ損なってなもんだろうがおう！](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/1478)
9. [一ヵ条: いちっかじょう? いちかじょう? いっかじょう?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/1478)
10. [What is the etymology of the word しょーむない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/1478)
11. [Can I use [自称]{じしょう}ほど for things other than namesake?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/1478)
12. [Stem classification 終止形 vs 連体形（しゅうしけい vs れんたいけい）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/1478)
13. [What is the correct reading for べき乗打切り待機法?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4207/1478)
14. ["To call" or "To receive a call"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/1478)
15. [What is the difference between 「食べるいいですか」 and 「食べていいですか」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/1478)
16. [two levels for teiru and rare](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/1478)
17. [Does the だ get dropped after an い-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/1478)
18. [「ありがとうございや」 - Dialect? Train Station 言葉？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/1478)

## What's next?

There's no time limit on participating in this clean-up effort.  You can still vote to close any question you think should be closed, whether you're reading this a day later or a year later. Just like always, the question will be added to the queue so everyone can review it. But for now, it looks our clean-up effort is largely complete.  I think we can safely remove the [source-error](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-error) tag from these questions.

Thanks to all the users who participated!